# Как сделать фиксированную верстку без meta viewport

Tags: javascript, html, html5, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Вопрос простой, как сделать фиксированную верстку (одинаковое отображение сайта на любой ширине и возможность его мастабирования) без использования запроса вида:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1660" />
```

Answer (score 0):

В фиксированной верстке мы задаем ширину контейнера в пикселях и, как правило выравниваем его посередине,

```
.container {
    width:980px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Вопрос не об этом. Интересует то, как написать скрипт, который заменит meta viewport.